# How many solutions are there to $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ such that for all $0\le x_i\le3$?

Tags: combinatorics, inclusion-exclusion

I know the general path is that k=10 and n=4, so it somehow relates to ${13 \choose 3}$.

I know I'm missing a part due to the constraint that all elements are between 0 and 3.

For now, $${13 \choose 3}$$ is as far as I could possibly get.

I'm stuck at a standstill here, I'm looking at problems similar to this yet I'm unable to make the connection.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Please edit your question to show what you have attempted and explain where you are stuck.  This [tutorial](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference) explains how to typeset mathematics on this site.  The formula you mentioned will help you get started on this problem.

Comment: have you heard of inclusion-exclusion ?

Comment: @trueblueanil yes, I'm somewhat aware that I need to implement it in this problem yet I don't really know how.

Comment: You don't need inclusion-exclusion here. Think about the following set $\{x_1+1, (x_1+1)+(x_2+1),(x_1+1)+(x_2+1)+(x_3+1)\}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hint:**

If some $x$ is $0$, you can't reach $10$. If some $x$ is $1$, the other three are $3$. If some $x$ is $2$, there's only one way to achieve $8$. Hence you permute $1,3,3,3$ and $2,2,3,3$ in all possible ways.

Comment: I've got that there are ${4 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}*{1 \choose 1}=4$ solutions in case one of the elements is 1, and ${4 \choose 1}*{3 \choose 1}*{2 \choose 1}=4!$ solutions in case of the elements is 2. does those solutions cover the options of one of the elements being a 3?

Comment: @Aishgadol: What if a single element is $3$ ? (And unfortunately your answer is wrong.)

Answer (score 2):

Well, you can look at it in the reverse way.

Suppose we give $3$ each to them, then we have given a total of $12$

We need to take away $2$ by either taking $2$ from any  one of them in $\binom41$ ways, or by taking $1$ each from any two in $\binom4 2$ ways, so....

or we can write $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4=2, y_i\geq0,$
$y_i$ referring to take away instead of give
and then apply the formula you talked about

Comment: I dont seem to understand what you're trying to show here, can you perhaps explain it in a different way? 

I'm not sure what the $y_i$ represents.

Comment: $y_i$ represents how many you *take away* from the $i_{th}$ person, having first given the maximum permissible $3$ to each of them.

Comment: can you share your solution to this problem? I'll put in the work needed to understand how to solve, mainly because all our problem sets come without any solution sheet, so we have no clue if we're correct or not.

Comment: Using the stars and bars formula with $k=2, n = 4$, we get $\binom{2+4-1}{4-1} = 10$. You would be well advised to also solve it conventionally using $x_i$ with inclusion-exclusion, which would be $\binom{13}3 - \binom41\binom9 3 + \binom 42\binom43$

Comment: I'll dedicate the time to understand your solution. when explaining about using the $y_i$ approach, does ${2+4-1 \choose 4-1}$ equal to the size of the group we're trying to count?

Comment: More formally, let $y_i= 3-x_i, y_i\geq 0$ then $x_1+x_2+x_3+x_4=10$ such that for all $0\le x_i\le3$ transforms to $y_1+y_2+y_3+y_4 = 2, y_i \geq0$ and solved using the stars and bars formula.

Comment: Thank you for your time and assistance, much appriciated!

Comment: Glad to be of help !